# Reading prop file bean error

Tags: java, xml, spring

Hy guys, I am trying to read a properties file and dispay it on the screen, but I am having trouble with my bean filE

Here is my bean file :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:fisier.properties." /> 

<bean id="fisier.properties" class="projectt.proiect.App">
    <property name="mesaj" value="${Hello}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

MY classes are this:

```
public class SecondClass {

    private String mesaj;

     public String getMesaj() {
            return mesaj;
        }

     public void setMesaj(String Mesaj) {
            this.mesaj = mesaj;
        }

     @Override
        public String toString(){
            return mesaj;
        }
}
```

And the main:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        String confFile = "bean.xml";

          ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(confFile);

          SecondClass secClass = (SecondClass) context.getBean("mesaj");
          System.out.println(secClass.toString());
          context.close();

}
}
```

I am getting the following error in the bean file : 
Attribute : name
The name of the property, following JavaBean naming conventions.

Data Type : string

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: paste the whole stack trace please?

Answer (score 0):

When you set your property, you have to put the class with that property:

```
<bean id="fisier.properties" class="SecondClass">
    <property name="mesaj" value="${Hello}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the errors. In the SecondClass i also meesd up the string setMesaj(String Mesaj) by putting the string with Uppercase M. I correct this and I don't have any errors but it stil dousen't work. Is there something wrong with the code in the SecondClass ?

Answer (score 0):

First, your bean type is incorrect:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:fisier.properties." /> 

<bean id="fisier.properties" class="projectt.proiect.SecondClass">
    <property name="mesaj" value="${Hello}" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Second, `getBean()` on the context, takes the id of your bean or the type:

```
    public class App 
    {
        public static void main( String[] args )
        {

            String confFile = "bean.xml";

              ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(confFile);

              SecondClass secClass = (SecondClass) context.getBean(projectt.proiect.SecondClass.class);
//or               SecondClass secClass = (SecondClass) context.getBean("fisier.properties");

              System.out.println(secClass.toString());
              context.close();

    }
    }
```

Thrid, your `setMesaj()` is incorrect:

```
public class SecondClass
{
  private String mesaj;

  public String getMesaj()
  {
    return mesaj;
  }

  public void setMesaj(String mesaj)
  {
    this.mesaj = mesaj;
  }

}
```

What do you want to do with que value ${Hello}?
Do you want to set mesaj property to "Hello"?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the errors. In the SecondClass i also meesd up the string setMesaj(String Mesaj) by putting the string with Uppercase M. I correct this and I don't have any errors but it stil dousen't work. Is there something wrong with the code in the SecondClass ?